# How to fix iBooks "Two pages" mode

Tags: preferences, books

I have a number of books in iBooks on my MacBook. All of them were showing nicely in "Two Pages" mode, until I clicked the "Show Notes" button, on two of them. Those books changed to "Single Page" mode and the "Two Pages" option under "View" is now disabled, even after disabling "Show Notes Panel" under "View".

I've already tried deleting everything under the /Users/jonasmatser/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks directory and adding the books back to the emptied iBooks application, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions what other preferences or files I could try to delete or other things I could do to get those books back in "Two Pages" mode?

Comment: Do two pages fit on the screen with 'Notes' on the side?

Comment: How about you go to iBooks Preferences, and check something from there.

Comment: Notes didn't fit next to two pages, which is why I turned them off again, but then I couldn't reenable two pages anymore.

Comment: There were no settings to be found that solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this problem before, and I managed to get back two-page functionality by switching iBooks to full screen mode.  You also might be able to get it back by adjusting the iBooks window size -- the bug appears to be triggered when iBooks assumes there isn't enough space in the window to display both pages.

Answer (score 1):

Click Zoom Out in the View drop-down menu to make the text font size smaller until Two Pages is a live button.

Answer (score 0):

Manually drag the window corner while in single page. Once large enough, iBook will sometimes auto resize to double page. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click and drag the border to make the book window wider.  Once you get to a certain width, it will go back to two page mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. View -> Hide Notes Panel
2. View -> Two Pages

Answer (score 0):

Click on the aA fonts, then see if scrolling view button is on green; if so, just turn it off and you should be all set.   This happened to me and I tried everything before going to Apple Store where they quickly got me back to 2 page view by doing this simple step!!!